# Where to get an updated list of video games?

Tags: database

I am currently designing a reviews site for video games similar to gamespot am wondering where and if there is an online database that contains information such as name, publisher, release date etc with an API. I dont really want to have to enter each title manually or let users enter the title manually.

Where do these large sites get information like this? I wouldn't think it would be manually. I know for movies IMDB exists.

How would I go about adding it to my database?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I point you to [web scraping?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_scraping)

Be sure to read the section legal issues and on well-behaved bots.

Answer (score 0):

There's always Amazon and their [product advertising API](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html).  Some older, but interesting code snippets can be found [on this page](http://www.codediesel.com/php/accessing-amazon-product-advertising-api-in-php/).

Answer (score 0):

If you know Perl, there is an amzing module called WWW::Mechanize
Pretty much you can write a script to get to any website and grab any data you need.
So for example you can go to www.gamespot.com, get list like the one below and put them in your database.
http://www.gamespot.com/games.html?platform=1029&mode=all&sort=views&dlx_type=all&sortdir=asc&official=all&tag=games%3Bfooter%3Bmore